# visual studio 2013 crashes when closing application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli, 64-bit

I started a new project in Visual Studio 2013, it give me a "hello world" example,
i modified it to:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
  {
    Console::WriteLine("Hello World");
    getchar();
    return 0;
  }
```

I just made the changes for the app waits for a command and close.
The application Works, but when i close it, Visual Studio crashes and the IDE freezes completely.The only way to close is using taskkill command in the prompt.

```
taskkill /IM WDExpress.exe /F
```

Compiled in debug mode, win 32 platform.

Excuse me for any english errors.

I not working with VS 2013 anymore, im using VS Express 2008 now.
VS Express 2008 doesn't compile in 64-bit at least, thats microsoft want.
I found this link:

http://jenshuebel.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/visual-c-2008-express-edition-and-64-bit-targets

that might be very useful for someone that want to compile 64 bit applications on VS Express 2008.
I don't know if it works on another versions.

Just added this to help.

Comment: VS bug... it happens... send a crash report to MS.

Comment: i searched for questions with the same idea, and the tags was exactly the same that i used. I thought that any other tags was unnecessary.

Comment: When there are hundreds of thousands of programmers that use it and only you or a few have a problem like this then it stops being a VS problem.  Get your machine stable again.

Comment: I agree with Hans.  It is foolish and reckless to blame VS for simple stuff like this.

Comment: I undestand Hans. I guess that the machine is with some problems.